# Acquiring a wake lock

Tags: ubuntu-touch, power-management, ubuntu-sdk

How do i aquire a wakelock on ubuntu phone? i tried with the usual android method:

```
echo something > /sys/power/wake_lock
```

but i get:

```
-bash: /sys/power/wake_lock: Permission denied
```

any help?

Comment: You probably need root privilege to do this